# Al utilizar lista enlazada se pierde los strings luego de retornar

Tags: c, lista, archivo, punteros

Quisiera saber como puedo arreglar lo siguiente, llevo bastante rato y no logro encontrar el error.
Necesito leer lo siguiente desde un archivo llamado generos.txt el cual contiene la cantidad de géneros en la primera linea y las demás lineas el identificador y su genero como tal.

```
4
1 terror
2 romance
3 aventuras
4 comedia
```

y necesito almacenarlos mediante a una lista simplemente enlazada, este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo{
    int id;
    char *nombre;
    struct nodo *sig;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;

nodo *crearNodo(int id, char *nombre){
    nodo *aux;
    aux = (nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    aux->id = id;
    aux->nombre = nombre;
    aux->sig = NULL;
    return aux;
}

nodo *agregarInicio(nodo *L,nodo *elemento){
    elemento->sig = L;
    return elemento;
}

void mostrarLista(nodo *L){
    nodo *aux;
    aux = L;
    while(aux != NULL){
        printf("ID: %d, Genero:%s\n",aux->id,aux->nombre);
        aux = aux->sig;
    }
}
nodo *leerGeneros(){
    FILE *generos;
    generos = fopen("generos.txt","r");
    nodo * L = NULL;

    if(generos == NULL){
        fclose(generos);
        return L;
    }
    else{
        int id,canGeneros,i=0;
        fscanf(generos,"%d",&canGeneros);
        
        char name[canGeneros][50];
        while(i<canGeneros){
            fscanf(generos,"%d %s",&id,&name[i]);
            nodo *aux =crearNodo(id,name[i]);
            L=agregarInicio(L,aux);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(generos);
        return L;
    }
}

int main(){ 
    nodo*listaGeneros = leerGeneros();
    mostrarLista(listaGeneros);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema viene siendo en el main cuando utilizo `mostrarLista(listaGeneros);` debido a que los identificadores se muestra correctamente pero en cambio los géneros solo salen caracteres sin sentido, y si trato de mostrar la lista enlazada antes del return en `leerGeneros()` se muestra correctamente, y no sé a lo que se puede deber esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lectura de cadenas de caracteres es un poco diferente a la lectura de otros tipos de variables.

Lo primero que te tiene que llamar la atención es que estás tratando con arrays:

```
char name[canGeneros][50]; // Array de 2 dimensiones

name[i]; // Array de 1 dimensión
```

Además hay que tener en cuenta que los arrays decaen a puntero, es decir, pueden sufrir una conversión implícita a punteros sin que tengas que programarlo explícitamente:

```
char* ptr = name[i];
```

Pues bien, fíjate que a la hora de leer los nombres haces lo siguiente:

```
fscanf(generos,"%d %s",&id,&name[i]);
```

Llama la atención que para `name` estés recuperando una posición de memoria con `&`, ya que, como has visto, `name[i]` ya te proporciona la dirección de memoria que estás buscando. Tienes que dejarlo así:

```
fscanf(generos,"%d %s",&id,name[i]);
```

Por otro lado, la variable `name` es una variable local de la función `leerGeneros`. Esto quiere decir que dicha variable dejará de existir cuando la ejecución abandone la función. La consecuencia es que la memoria utilizada por dicha variable pasará a estar disponible para cualquier otra variable que el programa necesite crear.

Esto no sería un problema si cada nodo almacenase la cadena de caracteres en su memoria interna, pero no es así. Si echamos un vistazo a la declaración de la estructura `nodo`, vemos que para el nombre utiliza un puntero:

```
struct nodo{
    int id;
    char *nombre; // <<--- puntero a char
    struct nodo *sig;
};
```

Por otro lado vemos que la lectura se limita a copiar en estos punteros una referencia al array `name` que hemos comentado antes:

```
aux->nombre = nombre;
```

Teniendo en cuenta que un puntero no es más que una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria, es decir, no almacena los valores que se encuentren en una posición de memoria sino que guarda la dirección de memoria en sí misma, lo que sucede aquí es que el puntero de cada nodo acaba referenciando una posición de `name`, una variable local. Cuando la variable deje de existir, los punteros quedarán en el limbo, apuntando a una dirección de memoria que podrá contener cualquier cosa.

Lo que tienes que hacer es darle memoria a los nodos para que puedan almacenar el texto en su memoria interna:

```
struct nodo{
    int id;
    char nombre[50];
    struct nodo *sig;
};
```

Ahora ya no funcionará eso de `aux->nombre = nombre`, ya que los arrays no se pueden copiar con el operador `=`, en su lugar debes usar una función tipo `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(aux->nombre, nombre);
```

Como ahora ya los nombres se almacenan en los nodos, ya no hace falta que `name` sea un array:

```
for( int i=0; i<canGeneros; i++)
{
    char name[50];
    fscanf(generos,"%d %s",&id,name);
    nodo *aux =crearNodo(id,name);
    L=agregarInicio(L,aux);
}
```